# Python Remove specific word only 1 time from string

Tags: python

I have a problem. I am trying to remove a specific word from a string like this:

```
sentence = "My father always told me to find a girl, so I can be a father in the future"
sentence = sentence.replace("father", '')
```

But I only want to remove the word father in the first part of the sentence. I can't find something like that on a python explanation of the replace function.

Is this possible and what do I need to use then?

Comment: Yes..... Just 1 variable more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just gotta add a number in `replace` to tell it how many times to replace.

```
sentence = sentence.replace("father", '', 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will accept when I can!

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) states:

> Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

So pass a 3rd argument, like so:

```py
sentence = "My father always told me to find a girl, so I can be a father in the future"
sentence = sentence.replace("father", '', 1)
print(sentence)
```

```
My  always told me to find a girl, so I can be a father in the future
```